# External keyboard stops Working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: keyboard

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 3 months ago, since then I had no issues with my external keyboard. But for the past 2 days, keyboard stops working all of a sudden and if I disconnect the external keyboard and connect it on another port, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work. I have tested the keyboard on other laptops and it works fine on other devices. Now what can I do?

Comment: It sounds like a hardware problem. Try booting from the live Ubuntu installation USB with the **Try Ubuntu** option and test your external keyboard from there. If the problem persists, it is a hardware problem. If not, [update your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1354405/edit) with the new information. Next, try booting from the previous kernel installed in your Ubuntu. If the problem does not happen with the older kernel, then there is a bug in the new kernel, and it needs to be reported.

Comment: How to downgrade to the previous kernel?

Comment: To boot to the previous kernel, you go to the Advanced grub menu at the boot time. If you don't see grub (to choose Windows or Ubuntu for example) when you boot your computer, then press and hod the ESC or the SHIFT key when the computer starts, before it gets to Ubuntu to reveal the grub menu. When you see it, you select Advanced. Then select the kernel version with the lower number from the top.